# Regex matching other group if the right one doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create 3 regex:

The first takes the fourth value after 07, after BASE CAL 13 PREV SOC and after FECHAMENTO - MODALIDADE : "BRANCO".

The second takes the fourth value after 07, after BASE CAL 13 PREV SOC and after FECHAMENTO - MODALIDADE : 1.

The third takes the fourth value after 07, after BASE CAL 13 PREV SOC and after FECHAMENTO - MODALIDADE : 7.

This are the regular expressions that I created, but they are wrong:

```
1. /\sFECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE :\s"BRANCO".*?BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC\s*?(?:(?:01|02|03|04|05|06)(?:\s[\d,.]+)+)?\s01(\s[\d,.]+){4}\s*?/

2. /\sFECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE :\s1.*?BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC\s*?(?:(?:01|02|03|04|05|06)(?:\s[\d,.]+)+)?\s07(\s[\d,.]+){4}\s*?/

3. /\sFECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE :\s9.*?BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC\s*?(?:(?:01|02|03|04|05|06)(?:\s[\d,.]+)+)?\s07(\s[\d,.]+){4}\s*?/
```

Demo:

1. Regex MODALIDADE : "BRANCO": http://regexr.com/3d02f is working properly, but it's because the 07 exists, if the 07 did not exist and it existed in MODALIDADE : 1, would get the wrong value.
2. Regex MODALIDADE : 1: http://regexr.com/3d02i is getting the value of MODALIDADE 9.
3. Regex MODALIDADE 9: http://regexr.com/3d02l is getting the correct value, but it could get the wrong value as the others are too.

The problem is the *? just after the BASE CAL PREV 13, is accepting everything to find a match. How could I fix this?

Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you problem correctly, you can:

1. Change `.*?` to `((?!FECHAMENTO).)*?` in every regex, it will prevent the `.*?`
   from overlapping to another `FECHAMENTO(...)` segment; like in:

   ```
   \sFECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE :\s"BRANCO"((?!FECHAMENTO).)*?(BASE CÁL) 13º PREV SOC\s*?(?:(?:01|02|03|04|05|06)(?:\s[\d,.]+)+)?\s(07)(\s[\d,.]+){4}\s*?
   ```

   [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nA0oU3/2)

   or...
2. As all your regexes are very similar, and differ with just one value
   (1,9,"BRANCO"), you can use one regex, and distingiush cases by this
   one value:

   ```
   \sFECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE :\s("BRANCO"|9|1)(?:(?!FECHAMENTO).)*?BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC\s*?(?:(?:01|02|03|04|05|06)(?:\s[\d,.]+)+)?\s07(?:\s([\d,.]+)){4}\s*?
   ```

   [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rL6kI8/2)

   just check which value was captured by group `$1`, and you will get
   corresponding value.

I think second option is better, but it is up to you.